# reactJS hooks asx Changing the style parameters for a div when it is clicked

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx

I have several elements with unique IDs and sharing the same className.  When a user clicks on one of these elements I want to change the background and text colour and the font.

I created two variables (Style1, Style2)which hold the style for the normal and clicked elements.  Style1 is for the clicked element.

```
const tileStyle1: CSS.Properties = {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    fontFamily: 'londrinaBlackRegular',
    color: 'yellow',
  };  

  const tileStyle2: CSS.Properties = {
    fontFamily: 'londrinaSketcheRegular'};
```

I created a third variable, tileStyle, which is embedded in the HTML for all the elements.  example:

```
<div className="linkcontainer" ID="Tile3" style={tileStyle} onClick={handleClick}>Marketing</div>

<div className="linkcontainer" ID="Tile4" style={tileStyle} onClick={handleClick}>Support</div>
```

I thought to set tileStyle for each element with a ternary operator:

```
{clickedTile = "Tile3" ? tileStyle = tileStyle1 : tileStyle = tileStyle2;}
<div className="linkcontainer" ID="Tile3" style={tileStyle} onClick={handleClick}>Support</div>

{clickedTile = "Tile4" ? tileStyle = tileStyle1 : tileStyle = tileStyle2;}

<div className="linkcontainer" ID="Tile4" style={tileStyle} onClick={handleClick}>Support</div>
```

But it appears these are not objects in the usual manner and this produces a big error: **Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys{fontFamily})...**

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a variable assignment in the return method since React will try to render it. You can however do so while assigning styles prop itself, where You put Your ternary expression (because code inside {} is evaluated as ordinary JS expression), in which You return dictionary.

```
<div className="linkcontainer" ID="Tile3" style={clickedTile === "Tile3" ? tileStyle1 : tileStyle2} onClick={handleClick}>Support</div>

<div className="linkcontainer" ID="Tile4" style={clickedTile === "Tile4" ? tileStyle1 : tileStyle2} onClick={handleClick}>Support</div>
```

Comment: This looks promising, but I am getting a compile-time error on the "===":   [Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","]

<div className="linkcontainer" ID="Tile2" style={{clickedTile === "Tile2" ? tileStyle1         : tileStyle2}} onClick={handleClick}>Support</div>   --------------- -------------------------- ^

Comment: @SunbeamRapier Code is fixed,there was extra brace...